# org.ros.internal.message cannot be cast to std_msgs.String

Tags: ros, eclipse, client-rosjava, rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm working recently with Rosjava Kinetic and I have some problems and doubts.
I have imported the project to Eclipse to mix it with another project that I have, called PELEA, composed of several modules, to make the message passing through a client-server.
Of course, I have a terminal running roscore and a server running inside eclipse.
I make the new client and the new message in this way:

```
public void onStart(final ConnectedNode connectedNode) {

    ServiceClient<std_msgs.String, std_msgs.String> serviceClient;

    try {
         serviceClient = connectedNode.newServiceClient("custom_service", std_msgs.String._TYPE); 
    } catch (ServiceNotFoundException e) {
              throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
    }
     
     final std_msgs.String request = serviceClient.newMessage(); //ERROR!!
     request.setData("Hello");  

     serviceClient.call(request, new ServiceResponseListener<std_msgs.String>() {

          @Override
        public void onSuccess(std_msgs.String response) {
        connectedNode.getLog().info(String.format("The response is: "));
                    response.getData();}
        @Override
        public void onFailure(org.ros.exception.RemoteException e) {
        throw new RosRuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

And I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ros.internal.message.$Proxy4 cannot be cast to std_msgs.String
    at org.squeleton.executiondeclarative.ExecutionSqueleton.clientManagement(ExecutionSqueleton.java:591)
    at org.squeleton.executiondeclarative.Client.onStart(Client.java:57)
    at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:507)
    at org.ros.internal.node.DefaultNode$5.run(DefaultNode.java:504)
    at org.ros.concurrent.EventDispatcher.loop(EventDispatcher.java:43)
    at org.ros.concurrent.CancellableLoop.run(CancellableLoop.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

So.. I don't know what is the problem, I think it should works..

I appreciate any help, advide or guide.

Thanks a lot and sorry for my bad english.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299085/org.ros.internal.message-cannot-be-cast-to-std_msgs.string/) by [A.Grag](https://answers.ros.org/users/36676/a.grag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-30**:
Just so you know, the `<pre>` and `<code>` tags don't do a very good job at marking up code and terminal output. It's usually easier to highlight the text then click on the `101010` button instead. That way your code is marked up with syntax highlighting.

**Comment by [A.Grag](https://answers.ros.org/users/36676/a.grag/) on 2018-07-30**:
Ok, you are right... sorry.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-07-30**:
It's not a problem, just for reference for the next time that you ask a question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@A.Grag `std_msgs.String` is a standard message, and you are dealing with service clients in that piece of code.

I suggest you to take a look at https://github.com/rosjava/rosjava_core/tree/kinetic/rosjava_tutorial_pubsub and http://wiki.ros.org/rosjava_build_tools/Tutorials/indigo/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28Java%29 first, I think you are mixing the concepts of messages and topics with services.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [A.Grag](https://answers.ros.org/users/36676/a.grag/) on 2018-08-03**:
Thanks for your answer. Finally, I found a way to create a custom message with genjava.